# Getting JavaScript error while handling autocomplete location data in Google maps API in VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a search input form where user will search for a location and nearby pharmacy list will be shown in the page in my VueJS 2 application. While searching the autocomplete is not working. It is showing Can not read property 'find' of undefined. The code is as follows:

```
<input
   id="District"
   name="District"
   class="form-control"
   data-live-search="true"
   list="places-list"
   v-model="searchString"
   @input="handleAutocomplete($event.target.value)"
   />
<datalist id="places-list">
   <option
      v-for="place in placesList"
      :value="place['description']"
      label=""
      :key="place['place_id']"
      >
      <!-- {{ place.name }} -->
   </option>
</datalist>


  export default {
    name: "PharmacyList",
    data() {
        return {
            longitude: "",
            latitude: "",
            searchString: "",
            pharmacyList: [],
            placesList: []
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        let success = position => {
            // Do something with the position
            this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            this.reverseGeocode();
            this.getpharmacylist();
        };
        const error = err => {
            //On geolocation error set defaults
            this.latitude = 23.7629088;
            this.longitude = 90.3794101;
            this.searchString = "Dhaka, Bangladesh";
            this.getpharmacylist();
        };
        // This will open permission popup
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    },
    methods: {
        callnow: function (number) {
            window.open("tel:" + number, "_self");
        },
        getpharmacylist: async function () {
            this.$axios
                .get(
                    "https://purnohealth.com/nearbysearch.php?" +
                    `location=${this.latitude},${this.longitude}&type=pharmacy`, {}
                )
                .then(
                    response => {
                        if (response.data.status != "OK") {
                            toast.$toast.error("Something Went Wrong at !", {
                                // override the global option
                                position: "top"
                            });
                        } else if (response.data.status == "OK") {
                            this.pharmacyList = [];
                            const pharmacies = response.data.results;
                            for (let i = 0; i < pharmacies.length; i++) {
                                let placeID = pharmacies[i]["place_id"];
                                this.$axios
                                    .get("https://purnohealth.com/getplace.php?place_id=" + placeID, {})
                                    .then(
                                        response => {
                                            if (response.data.status != "OK") {
                                                toast.$toast.error("Something Went Wrong at !", {
                                                    // override the global option
                                                    position: "top"
                                                });
                                            } else if (response.data.status == "OK") {
                                                this.pharmacyList.push(response.data.result);
                                            }
                                        },
                                        error => {
                                            toast.$toast.error(
                                                "Could not connect to Backend!! Please try again", {
                                                    position: "top"
                                                }
                                            );
                                        }
                                    );
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    error => {
                        toast.$toast.error(
                            "Could not connect to Backend!! Please try again", {
                                position: "top"
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
        },
        handleAutocomplete: async function (query) {
            if (query.length < 3) return;
            try {
                const {
                    data: {
                        predictions
                    }
                } = await this.$axios.get(
                    "https://purnohealth.com/autocomplete.php?" + `input=${query}`
                );
                this.placesList = predictions;
                this.handleSearch(query);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        },
        handleSearch: async function (description) {
            const place = this.placesList.find(p => p["description"] === description);
            if (place && place["place_id"]) {
                try {
                    const {
                        data: {
                            result: {
                                geometry: {
                                    location
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } = await this.$axios.get(
                        "https://purnohealth.com/getplace.php?place_id=" + place["place_id"]
                    );
                    this.latitude = location.lat;
                    this.longitude = location.lng;
                    this.getpharmacylist();
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        },
        reverseGeocode: async function () {
            const {
                data: {
                    results
                }
            } = await this.$axios.get(
                "https://purnohealth.com/geocoding.php?latlng=" +
                `${this.latitude},${this.longitude}`
            );
            if (results && results.length > 0) {
                this.searchString = results[0].formatted_address;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

How can I solve the error? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are assigning `undefined` to `this.placeList` in the `handleAutocomplete` method. And I'm guessing that happens because the API you're querying doesn't actually seem to return a valid JSON result. If I query it for "foo", I get this:

`foo{ "predictions" : [ ... ], "status" : "OK" }`

That's invalid JSON; "foo" should be removed for it to be valid JSON (and for Axios to be able to parse it, I guess). Obvious solution is to fix the API, but it also probably wouldn't hurt to program a little more defensively:

```
try {
    const {
        data: {
            predictions
        }
    } = await this.$axios.get(
        `https://purnohealth.com/autocomplete.php?input=${query}`
    );
    if (!Array.isArray(predictions) {
        throw "Predictions is not an array.";
    }
    this.placesList = predictions;
    this.handleSearch(query);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: I tried. Still the same https://purnohealth.com/#/nearbypharmacy

Comment: O. json was not well structured. Now its working. Thanks.